# Outdoor Motion Sensor Light Fixture proper fish wiring

Tags: wiring, lighting

Hello: I am trying to find a better way to wire and connect the outdoor Motion sensor light (top corner of the house) from the internal power source (outlet, switch). Could you please advise the right way to do it. I have the outlet inside the room on the same wall and the outdoor outlet (but it's far from the intended light location). Shall I use some other power sources or go from the attic route and find some power source through that? I looked on YouTube and many other forums but can't find a proper way. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You just need to find almost any electrical point to connect the light from. Probably the closest to the new light location. But also check what else is on the circuit that you plan to add it to and make sure you won't overload it. This is too vague of a question. We could help explain wiring and connection, but we don't know your house or where it could be connected.

Comment: some solar options perform very well these days, might be worth looking into, if the extra $50 is worth avoiding the attic to you...